# how can i access vuejs data in method

Tags: javascript, arrays, laravel-5, vue.js, momentjs

I have saved a collection of data from database to an array in `vue.js` using ajax request in laravel. I want to get some data from that collection inside a method so that i can make more data for the body but somehow I can not access it. for example, by using the code below.

```
var vm = this;
$.get('url', function (response) {
      vm.time_slots = response;
      for( i=0; i < vm.time_slots.length; i++){  //also tried with var/let i
         if(i=0){
            console.log(vm.time_slots[i].start_time);
         }else if(vm.time_slots[i].start_time > vm.time_slots[i-1].start_time){
           console.log(vm.time_slots[i].start_time);
         }
      }
     }, 'json');
```

i get undifined. but if i access it through the console i get what i need. below is the data.

```
data: {
  time_slots: [],
  current_timeslots: []
},
```

now each time_slot in time_slots has a start_date end_date etc. i want to access them but i get undefined. even **this.time_slots.length** is returned as 0, while if i check in console i get 12.
how can i access data with in the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.get` performs an *asynchronous* HTTP request. The data you get back from that request is only available inside the callback function.

```
var vm = this;

$.get('url', function (response) {
  // This code executes once the data is available
  vm.time_slots = response;

  // This works
  console.log(vm.time_slots[0]);
}, 'json');

// This line executes immediately after the above HTTP request is
// sent but not yet resolved, so the data isn't available
console.log(vm.time_slots[0]);
```

It's important to understand how AJAX requests work, in particular the async nature of performing such HTTP requests in JavaScript.

You should put breakpoints at various spots in the above code and step through the execution paths in the browser's debugger to see just how it works.

Here's another (simpler) example which demonstrates how this works:

```
var data = 'hello';

setTimeout(function() {
  data = 'world';
  console.log('inside callback: ' + data);
}, 1000);

console.log('outside callback: ' + data);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer i really didnt know . but what can i do to solve this?

Comment: You can't access `vm.time_slots` until the request has completed, meaning you need to move all code after the `$.get` call into the callback function like I have shown. There's no way around this. HTTP requests in JavaScript are always non-blocking and asynchronous.

Comment: is there any other way than $.get call?

Comment: There are other ways to perform a HTTP request (namely [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)), but they are all async. *Technically* there is a [synchronous API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests), but I've never used it and I very strongly discourage you from using it because it will probably block all JavaScript until the request is resolved which is a very poor user experience (that API is deprecated; I feel bad even mentioning it to you, please don't use it :) ).

Comment: i tried to put the code inside the request but i still cant access data in a for loop

Comment: It seems there is more to your question that what you posted. Can you update your question with the for loop?

Comment: i edited the code now can you check? take your time if your busy .

Comment: `if (i=0)` should be `if (i === 0)` and `vm.time_slots[i-1]` will be `undefined` when `i === 0` because you're trying to access the element before the first (index -1) which doesn't exist. Set a breakpoint in the callback function and step through the code to see what's happening.

Comment: OH MY GOD! how dumb a person can be? Thank you so much and sorry for taking so much of your time. now im gonna go cry in corner for how dumb i am.

Answer (score 0):

I think it seems more about asynchronous problem than Vuejs problem. You just need to remember how asynchronous call behave in javascript. Asynchronous call will execute it's task without blocking the next line of code. In other words, asynchronous call will executed almost at the same time the next line of code executed. For your case:

```
$.get('url', function (response) {
  // if you want to do operations (formatting data, do some calculation, or set your vue instance data) immediately after $.get returns data, put your operations inside this callback

}, 'json');
// this is the next line of code, and will be executed almost at the same time $.get executed
// if you put those operations here (outset $.get method), $.get method hasn't finished yet because asynchronous call need more time to finish, so you don't have any data to be processed at that time, that's why it show 'undefined'
```

Why accessing from console returns data? It's because the $.get has already finished before you access your console. If you're unlucky or $.get need more time to finish than the time you access the console, you wouldn't get the data anyway

Hope this can help